# I am altering a variable, but how can i return the original state of it at the end of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

*I edited the post to get the word cross sum instead of factorial in it, thanks for your help.*

```
def assignment_2():
    # write a function that outputs the cross sum of a number (54321 -> 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15)

    number = int(input('enter a number'))
    result = 0

    while number:
        result = result + number % 10
        number = int(number / I0)
    return result, number
```

when I call the function I get the result no problem, but the number is = 0 because its going through that loop.

That's how I call the function

```
result, number = assignment_2()
print(f'assignment 2: the cross sum of {number} is {result}')
```

Comment: What is the value of `I0`?

Answer (score 2):

Just save the value to another variable:

```
number = int(input('enter a number'))
orig = number
result = 0

while number:
    result = result + number % 10
    number = int(number / 10)
return result, orig
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to save it in another variable:

```
number = int(...)
saved_number = number

...

return result, saved_number
```

Also, I should note that what you're doing here is not the factorial, but the *digit sum*. Factorial is the product of all numbers from 1 to the argument—for instance, 5 factorial is 5×4×3×2×1 = 120.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the input value as a string to get the digit sum, your algorithm does not need to transform its input at all:

```
def digit_sum(x):
    return sum(int(xx) for xx in str(x)), x

def assignment_2():
    return digit_sum(int(input("Please enter a number ")))
```